# How to choose "Multinominal" & "Bionominal" in SPSS Modeler?

Tags: spss-modeler

I'm trying to make a simple model, at the final stage, I have 2 options as a procedure (i) Multinominal (ii) Bionominal. But when I'm choosing "Bionominal" it's giving me an error & not executing, please find the attachment below. Please advise if I can change this procedure & make it as my desire. Thank you in advance.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JlS6.png)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the underlying data, it is hard to say for certain, but my best guess is that you have the target field defined with measurement level `Nominal` or `Ordinal`.

Since the binomial logistic regression only functions with a binary target, the measurement level must be set as `Flag` for you to use the binomial procedure.

If your target does indeed have more than 2 values, then you need to use the Multinomial procedure.